# Why does it give an error when I run 'npm install' in my terminal?

Tags: npm-install

PS C:\Users\JOEKINZ\Desktop\theaccrahandyman\budgettracker\frontend> npm install
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JOEKINZ\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-06-29T09_51_40_878Z-debug.log

Comment: please could You provide Your file & folder structure and code ?

Comment: I run npm config set prefix "$APPDATA\npm" and it WORKED for me. So it does not give ERROR when I run 'npm install'. I am good to go